# Order graph nodes d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, graph-visualization

I have a database where I maintain an entity Ids in one table while maintaining a source and target entity on other table.

I have generated a json of nodes and links. and used the following example as a reference (thought it would be enough to only generate the json file):

[Force directed graph for D3.js v4 with labelled edges and arrows](http://bl.ocks.org/fancellu/2c782394602a93921faff74e594d1bb1)

[Same code with my generated data](http://jsfiddle.net/kr1pvzem/)

The issue is that the graph is messy and I can't infer anything by looking at it. so what I'm trying to do is, since I am familiar with the relations between the entities I would like the nodes to be ordered top down by labels by some certain order. e.g *siteref* `->` *ro* `->` *ba* `->` *gr* `->` *ca*

Is that achievable at all? I have looked around for some other examples but did not find anything that could suit my needs.

Answer (score 2):

You can add [forceY](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#forceY), and optionally pass it a `strength`. In the forceY function you can set to return 0 for `siteref`, 100 for `ro`, and so on. Then you can tune in at your needs by playing a little bit with the strength in the links and in the different forces. Here is an updated fiddle so you can take a look at the idea. [Update fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8p92yLh/)